# IR Arduino Transmit n Receive

Tags: arduino, infrared

I am using digital IR Receiver Module and digital IR Transmitter Module connected each with different Arduino Uno. How can I transmit data like "1234" to the receiver and display data on LCD? This is because most of the example that I found using IR remote code like Sony and RC4. I just want to send a simple data.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use one of the existing IR code libraries such as RC5, which has numeric codes for buttons 0-9 on a remote.

Answer (score 6):

As the question does not state which digital IR Transmitter and Receiver modules are in use, this answer explains how infrared data communication can be achieved using simply a generic IR LED, and a modulated IR receiver such as Vishay's [TSOP17xx](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets/208/301092_DS.pdf) or other similar parts.

**Assumptions**:

- IR LED chosen can be driven with 20 mA current, e.g. [IR333](http://www.everlight.com/datasheets/IR333_H0_L10_datasheet.pdf)
- **TSOP1756** sensor is to be used (56 KHz modulation).

  - Change modulation frequency according to actual part used in sensor module. For TSOP11 **38**, for instance, modulation frequency is 38 KHz.

---

**Receiving**:

This is the easy part. Simply connect the OUT pin of the sensor to the serial RX pin of your Arduino (digital **Pin 0**). If your Arduino is one of the basic (older) models, use `Serial.read()` in `loop()`:

```
int inputByte = 0;
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    inputByte = Serial.read();
    // Do stuff with this byte, then loop again
```

For the Arduino *Mega* or *Due*, you can also use Serial1, Serial2 or Serial3, depending on which RX pin you use.

For additional reference, see the [Arduino Serial reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/serial).

**N.B.** Power the sensor with the same voltage as your Arduino *actually runs its microcontroller at*, either 3.3 or 5 Volts depending on Arduino model. Each Arduino board has a suitable voltage output pin you can use for this. Do ***not*** use the external supply (7 to 12 Volts typically) provided to the Arduino board.

---

**Transmitting**:

You have two options: (1) Arduino, LED and passive components, or (2) using an additional logic gate component. The first option is good for low-current IR LEDs (20-30 mA tops):

- Set one of the Arduino timers (Timer1 for instance, it is a 16-bit timer) for the modulation frequency, with output to one of the timer pins D9 or D10 associated with this timer.
- For a 16 MHz Arduino, to get approximately 56 KHz, use a counter overflow value of 286 ( = `55,944 Hz`). An overflow value of 421 will deliver `38,005 Hz` instead, if needed.
- Connect a suitable current limiting resistor (*120 to 150 Ohms on a 5 Volt Arduino = approximately **18 mA to 23 mA** limit*), a small signal diode, and the LED in series as shown below:

  [image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcAyt2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- When the TX pin is high, the LED will be pulsed at the modulation frequency. When TX pin is low, the LED will not light up, and the small-signal diode in series will protect the LED from reverse breakdown.
- If your Arduino is the 3.3 Volt type, then the small-signal diode is not really essential.

---

**For driving a higher current LED**, an additional logic component, a quad AND gate such as [SN74AS1008](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sdas071b/sdas071b.pdf) can be used. This part sources or sinks up to 48 mA per gate, and multiple gates can be paralleled for higher current drive.

- Connect the Timer1 output as set up above, to one input of each of the AND gates.
- Connect the TX output as mentioned above, to the second input of each of the AND gates.
- Connect a current limiting resistor of suitable value to each output pin of these 4 AND gates - such that the sum of the 4 output currents equals the desired drive current on the LED
- Connect the other ends of the 4 current limiting resistors to the Anode of the LED, with the Cathode connected to Arduino ground.
- You may have to supply the AND gate's Vcc from an external (5 Volts) power supply, since the Arduino's on-board regulator will overheat if too much current is drawn through it. Make sure the ground of this external supply is connected to Arduino GND.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fno0E1.png)</sup>

---

Now simply use `Serial.write()` in your Arduino `loop()` code, to transmit any serial data, which will be received by the `Serial.read()` at the other end, as described previously.